# Spark MySQL JDBC hangs without errors

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, mysql-connector

I have a simple application ingesting MySQL tables into S3 running on Spark 3.0.0 (EMR 6.1).

The MySQL table is loaded using a single large executor with 48G of memory as follows:

```
spark.read \
        .option("url", jdbc_url) \
        .option("dbtable", query) \
        .option("driver", driver_class) \
        .option("user", secret['username']) \
        .option("password", secret['password']) \
        .format("jdbc").load()
```

The Spark jobs work without any problem on small tables where the MySQL query takes less than ~6 minutes to complete. However, in two jobs where the query goes beyond this time the Spark job gets stuck RUNNING and does not trigger any error. The stderr and stdout logs don't show any progress and the executor is completely healthy.

The dag is very simple:

[image]

In MYSQL (Aurora RDS) the query seems to be completed but the connection is still open, while checking the thread state it shows 'cleaned up'.

I have tried with the MySQL connector version 5 and 8, but both of them show the same behaviour. I guess this could be related to a Spark default timeout configuration, but I would like to have some guidance.

This is a Thread Dump of the single executor:

[image]

Comment: May be you database node is too small?

Comment: Thanks @A.B I don't think that's the problem because the resources in Aurora are always below 40%. Also the query seem to finish correctly, it moves to 'cleaned up' state. I also did a tcpdump in EMR and when the query ends in Aurora no more packets are received.

Comment: did you solve this? having similar issues